# Choosing value of Moran's I to say existence of spatial correlation?

Tags: spatial-statistics, autocorrelation, moran-index

I am a GIS beginner. Usually we use Moran's I to evaluate spatial autocorrelation. Everyone knows the Moran's I coefficient ranges from -1 (uniform) to 1 (clustering); `I = 0` means no correlation.

If `I = 0.2, 0.3, 0.4` (suppose `I` is statistically significant; i.e. p-value is small, like `p < 0.05`), do we say there exists spatial correlation?

How large I coefficient we claim `strong` spatial correlation empirically?

Or we should proceed to run a spatial regression model, and then observe how significant on lag y or lag error coefficients to make conclusion?

Comment: Well, if you think back to your course work, would this not depend on a p or z value? Without a significance test, the question is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: @Jeffery I slightly revised the statement. Suppose the p-value is small enough to reject null hypothesis. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I myself am still learning as much as I can about Moran's I, but I think I help figure out the answer to this question.  There is a great video on [coursera about spatial correlation](https://www.coursera.org/learn/spatial-data-science/lecture/zIO0y/spatial-autocorrelation):

> Based on the Z-score, a statistical test is feasible to check if a
>   given variable is spatially autocorrelated or not. The statistical
>   test can be formulated like this, Null hypothesis, H0, is spatial
>   autocorrelation does not exist. Alternative hypothesis, H1, is spatial
>   autocorrelation exist. The Z-score is the test statistic. And
>   dependent on the value of Z-score, we can either accept H0, null
>   hypothesis, or reject H0. For example, Z-score is bigger than 1.96,
>   then you can say at the confidence level of 95 percent, this variable
>   has a positive spatial autocorrelation. Or if the value of Z-score is
>   a smaller than 1.96, then you can say, at the confidence level of 95
>   percent, the null hypothesis is accepted, meaning that no spatial
>   autocorrelation exists.

So like Frank mentioned you need to calculate a Z-score.  Now to calculate the Z-score you need the mean which for Moran's I `-1/(N -1)` where N is the number of samples.  This number serves as a baseline for what your correlation values should be like.

From what I have read about spatial correlation generally most people either choose p-value of .10 or .05 to say that the autocorrelation is statistically significant.  In the quote above the professor considers using a p-value of .05 for statistical significance, while in [ARGIS's documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/what-is-a-z-score-what-is-a-p-value.htm) you will find they use a p-value of .10.

Because this is slightly subjective, I have reproduced a more detailed table for Z-scores to P-values to Confidence Intervals for the Z-test.

Here is a brief table for Z-score assuming its just the basic Z-test:

```
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
| Confidence Interval | Positive Z-Score | Negative Z-Score | Pvalue  |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
| 99.9%               |             3.27 |            -3.27 |   0.001 |
| 99.73%              |             3.00 |            -3.00 |   0.020 |
| 99%                 |            2.576 |           -2.576 |   0.010 |
| 98%                 |            2.326 |           -2.326 |   0.020 |
| 95.45%              |             2.00 |           -2.000 |   0.046 |
| 95%                 |             1.96 |            -1.96 |   0.050 |
| 90%                 |            1.645 |           -1.645 |   0.100 |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+---------+
```

P.S. I also learned a little myself, as I thought that strength rules for spatial correlation matched the strength rules for correlation (I >.8 being the very strong relationship and .6 < weak relationship ).  Though Moran's I is a weighted Pearson correlation, it not true that you can interpret the values similar to regular correlations when you compare.   Like Jeffery Evans mentioned, you need to consider the p and z-values to test statistical significance to really interpret the spatial autocorrelation because tails represent a different spatial process (vs. regular correlation).  According to [Yanguang Chen](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0126158) spatial auto-correlation is only one piece figuring the spatial relationship between two variables, you need to consider the spatial cross-correlation.  In fact, the Pearson Correlation between any two spatial variables is the combination of the direct correlation and this spatial-cross correlation.

Comment: Common statistical practice would evaluate statistical significance at a minimum of the 95% confidence or p=0.05 which gives you a +/- critical z-value of 1.96. I would not go with ESRI's recommendation of p=0.10. As far as the "strengths of correlation" one should keep in mind that Moran's-I is really nothing more than a spatially weighted Pearson's correlation. There is some interesting work by Chen (2015) showing the indexes local and global decomposability into an eigenvector.

Comment: Hrmm... Wait... was I then right the scale or "strength of correlation" for spatial was similar to how we determine the [strength or magnitude for Pearson correlations](http://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/how-to-interpret-a-correlation-coefficient-r/)?  I thought I might have been wrong.  Also do you have the link by Chen (2015) or his first name?  It might be interesting to add.

Comment: I have these cross-correlation methods available in R via the crossCorrelation function in the spatialEco package. Here is the citation: Chen., Y. (2015) A New Methodology of Spatial Cross-Correlation Analysis. PLoS One 10(5):e0126158. doi:10.1371/journal.pone.0126158

Comment: I think I'd rather see a variogram than a Moran's I statistic.

Comment: @Spacedman, indeed! Although, I really like the Borcard & Legendre "principal coordinates of neighbour matrices" method as well.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Thanks for the replay, I have edited the last line to match, what I think you were trying to say, in your first comment.  Please make sure the last line following what you are talking about. (P.S. The reason I am asking for a mini-review.  I am still trying to figure out how I take an autocorrelation (comparing a measure to itself) and then use that to spatially relate or compare two equally distributed measures.  In my case, I have ""zip codes"" or ZCTA census data in a .shp file.)

Comment: The interpretation of the index is a bit different that a straight correlation, instead representing different types of spatial process on the two tails.